# How to return a TDataSet from REST sever written in Delphi DataSnap and load it in TFDmemTable on client

Tags: delphi, rest, mobile, datasnap

I tried this for many times and without result. I wrote a Datasnap REST server in Delphi returning a TDataSet, like this.

```
function Filter(Value: string): TDataSet;
```

on client side I receive a JSON with following structure.

> {"Value":"","result":{"table":[["ID",6,0,0,0,4,0,0,false,false,0,false,false],["UName",1,1,0,50,51,0,0,false,false,0,false,false],["UPass",1,2,0,50,51,0,0,false,false,0,false,false],["Prezime",1,3,0,50,51,0,0,false,false,0,false,false],
>   ...

It is obvious that result is in JSON and every Column is in one separate JSONAray.

But, when I pull this to client through TRestClient, TRestRequest and TRestResponse and try to connect it to TFDmemTable over TRESTResponseDataSetAdapter, I can not do that.

I did it with servers made in C# and PHP, but not with Delphi made server.

Did anyone passed this way from beginning to end?

Comment: You'll maybe get more responses if you explain a bit more about what your problem actually is.  "I can not do that" doesn't really tell the reader anything.

Comment: I suppose this is a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20481410) - see [my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23721110/458259) - it does not use a DataSnap REST server, but our Open Source `mORMot`, which is known [to scale much better on production](http://robertocschneiders.wordpress.com/2012/11/22/datasnap-analysis-based-on-speed-stability-tests/).

Comment: Thanks MartynA. I need to get a TDataSet from server and put it in TFDmemTable on client (mobile client). The issue I see is that

Comment: Thanks MartynA. I need to get a TDataSet from server and put it in TFDmemTable on client (mobile client). The issue I see is that structure of JSON received from TDataSet has a "strange" structure and I can not convert in to TFDmemTable. It seems that solution placed by  Arnaud Bouchez solves the problem (I tried it in a same manner). Maybe solution with TJSONReflect blogged by Marco Cantu can solve this.